# How to make multi user website with the same roles

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a website with some data visible to the user but things are happening in a different way.  When I log in, I get some rows from the database and again If I log in from the other username that time also I am getting the same details as earlier. But I want to display rows with respect to the user. For example, Leave balance if I take 3 leaves out of 15 then I log in from my friend account that time also I am getting same leave balance. I want to do it like Facebook. What is the right way to make it work just like Facebook and what are the steps to do it?
I am Using PHP, MYSQL.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a php function :

```
session_destroy();
```

To destroy the last user session on logout that why you still have same thing for next login

check the instruction : 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: that is not a problem.

Comment: if I take 3 holidays, that will deduct from my account that remaining holiday details should show to me with my account but if I log in with others account that time also that showing the page as visible from my account.

Comment: pull only respective data related to particular user, make a relation to your leave data and user